# Element is not clickable in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am facing issue while interacting with any element in a modal popup. I am using ChromeDriver 2.46 and all tests which involves modal popup fails on Chrome 74.

I get below error

`element is not clickable. Other element would receive the click`

I have tried with `scrollToTop`, `scrollToElement` and `visibilityOf` but nothing worked. Has anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: Is it possible for you to show your html or your code snippet. It will help me to understand/debug your issue. It does not look like any driver compatibility issue; most probably script issue.

Answer (score 1):

Attach you html, and full error stack

Meanwhile here is my assumption which is 90% likely what your problem is

Lets assume your html is something like

```
<div>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

your button is visible... but so is `div` element. BUT because  wraps the button, it is above the button (has higher z-index). That's why when you click button, div gets this click, which protractor doesn't let happen. And fails

In this case just simply use js click

```
browser.executeScript(
  "arguments[0].click();",
  $element.getWebElement() // substitute $element to your elementFinder
)
```

this will work because element gets the click regardless of visibility and the page layout

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Driver version and chrome version incompatibility could be the reason for your problem. Since chrome driver 2.46 supports v71-73 and you are using v74. We also observed that there are many evident instances of this. I would suggest first make sure that drive and chrome browser compatibility before running any test case.

[Refer this link for browser and driver compatibility](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)