# Unable to click on button using protractor. Button text is in child span

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

Unable to click a button using protractor. The DOM is as shown in the pic.

Below are some the of locators that I've already tried.

1. element(by.xpath("(//div[@class='mat-drawer-backdrop ng-star-inserted'])[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar9OT.png)//following-sibling::mat-sidenav//div//mat-nav-list//button"))
2. element(by.xpath("((//div[@class='mat-drawer-inner-container'])[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar9OT.png)//button//div)"))
3. element(by.deepCss("mat-button-ripple mat-ripple"))
4. element(by.deepCss("mat-button-wrapper"));
5. element(by.xpath("//div[@class='mat-button-focus-overlay']"))
6. element(by.xpath("//span[contains(.,' LOOK ')]"))
   and some more with xpath, cssContainingText combinations

Error 1 : is not clickable at point (78, 106). Other element would receive the click: ...

Error 2 :  No element found using locator: By(css selector, * /deep/ mat-button-ripple mat-ripple) and some more

Expected: Look button to be clicked
Actual: Click not landing on the button

Comment: Also tried maximizing the window size just to make sure there is no overlay of elements. Not much of a use.

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471741/element-is-not-clickable-in-protractor/56480132#56480132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I don't have your html page source, so i will start to see from  . Following html page, if you using object page in protractor, you can use :

```
var EC =  protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var button = element(by.css("mat-slidenav.layout-navigator .mat-nav-list button.mat-list-header"));


this.clickLookButton = function(){
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(button));
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(button));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button.getWebElement());
};
```

You can use protractor click function instead of code line

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button.getWebElement());
```

If you use protractor click function :

```
button.click();
```

Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when you get the Error 1, you are correctly locating the element, it's just returning the `not clickable at point...` error. You could try creating a function that scrolls to that element, then waits for it to be clickable. Try the following:

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
const yourElement = ;  // <--- whatever locator worked

const clickElement = async () => {
    await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)', yourElement.getWebElement());
    await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(yourElement), 5000);
    await yourElement.click();
};
```

Also try this type of locator too:
`element(by.css('.mat-nav-list.mat-list-base button span'));`