# Protractor: Selecting an Element

Tags: protractor

I want to select a button, so that I can do a click on it, but nothing that I have tried for selecting it has worked.

These are things that I have tried that haven't worked. Most of them result in an error that the selector is invalid.

```
element(by.css('md-card-actions>button>span')).click();

element(by.css('md-card-actions class="stepper-buttons ng-scope layout-row" layout="row" ng-if="vm.stepperFactory.controls" style="'));

element(by.className('stepper-buttons layout-row')).click();

element.all(by.className('flex')).get(2).click();

element(by.css('md-card-actions>button')).click();

element(by.css('md-card-actions')).click();

element(by.className('stepper-buttons ng-scope layout-row')).click();

element(by.css('md-card-actions class="stepper-buttons ng-scope layout-row" layout="row" ng-if="vm.stepperFactory.controls"')).click();

element(by.css('md-card-actions class="stepper-buttons ng-scope layout-row" layout="row"')).click();

element(by.css('md-card-actions class="stepper-buttons ng-scope layout-row"')).click();
```

This is the application code that contains the Continue to Demographics button, which I want to select:

```
<md-card-actions class="stepper-buttons layout-row" layout="row" ng-if="vm.stepperFactory.controls">
         <!-- BACK Button -->
    <!---->
    <!-- Spacer -->
    <span flex="" class="flex"></span>
    <!-- NEXT Button -->
    <button class="md-raised md-button md-ink-ripple md-accent" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-class="{ 'md-primary' : !vm.stepperFactory.lastStep, 'md-accent' : vm.stepperFactory.lastStep }" ng-disabled="!vm.stepperFactory.nextButton.active||!stepperForm.$valid" ng-click="vm.stepperFactory.goNext(stepperForm)"><span>
        Continue to Demographics
    </span></button>
</md-card-actions>
```

Comment: Have you tried `element(by.buttonText('Continue to Demographics'));`?

Comment: Thank you, but I got a response that the element is not clickable and another element should receive the click. I tried putting using that element name, but it didn't work either.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56480132/9150146

Answer (score 0):

similar to the first one you tried, but a bit different might work:

`element(by.css('.md-card-actions .md-raised.md-button.md-ink-ripple.md-accent span'));`

Comment: Thank you, but I still got a No element found response.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code snippet

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled=false;
element(by.buttonText('Continue to Demographics'));
```

Comment: Thank you, but I got this response.

Failed: False is not defined

Comment: Try using false in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a span inside your button. And 'Continue to Demographics' text is inside this span.
Please try this:

```
element(by.xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Continue to Demographics")]'))
```

UPDATE:
Try to use expect condition to wait for element to be clickable

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var myButton = element(by.xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Continue to Demographics")]'))
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(myButton), 10000, "element is not clickable");
```

In case you will get a timeout error ("element is not clickable") this will mean that my suggestion for locator is wrong. Please let me know

Comment: Thank you, but this is the response I get:
Element <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">...</span> is not clickable at point (1240, 978). Other element would receive the click: <md-card-actions class="stepper-buttons ng-scope layout-row" layout="row" ng-if="vm.stepperFactory.controls">...</md-card-actions>

Comment: There was no error, but it did not click the button. I don't know why some of my attempts result in the "is not clickable" response, because the button really is clickable. Thanks for trying again.

Comment: @DFG so let me clarify: 'elementToBeClickable' does not resolve with the error but then you get ' is not clickable' error? I mean if you set expected condition for the element to be clickable it  should fail if the element is not clickable. Or you did not tried the expected condition?